# Manipulate df with multiple time-series into array (with missing dates filled)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a relatively large df (10^6 records) structured as such:

```
Date,SN,Zip Code,A,B,Total,Lat,Lon
2015-09-01,10948.0,80015,0,0,1,39.626999999999995,-104.779
2015-09-01,11906.0,85392,0,0,1,33.478,-112.309
2015-09-03,10948.0,85260,0,0,1,33.611,-111.891
2015-09-03,11906.0,85050,0,0,1,33.683,-111.99799999999999
2015-09-05,12111.0,23834,0,0,1,37.291,-77.404
2015-09-05,11906.0,72761,0,0,1,36.169000000000004,-94.455
```

Notice that each `SN` (unique identifier) has **at most** 1 record per day. On some days, some `SN` have no record which means that the `Total` was 0 for the day. I want to take this df and convert into a numpy array that will show the `Total` for each day (rows) and `SN` (columns), but fill in the days that are missing for a `SN` with a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `pivot`:

```
df.pivot('Date', 'SN', 'Total').fillna(0)

#SN         10948.0 11906.0 12111.0
#Date           
#2015-09-01     1.0     1.0     0.0
#2015-09-03     1.0     1.0     0.0
#2015-09-05     0.0     1.0     1.0
```

To get the `numpy` array:

```
df.pivot('Date', 'SN', 'Total').fillna(0).values
#array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

*Update* to get all dates, you can use `reindex`:

```
# convert Date column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
​
# pivot to wide format
df1 = df.pivot('Date', 'SN', 'Total').fillna(0)
​
# reindex to get all dates
df1.reindex(pd.date_range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max())).fillna(0)

#        SN 10948.0 11906.0 12111.0
#2015-09-01     1.0     1.0     0.0
#2015-09-02     0.0     0.0     0.0
#2015-09-03     1.0     1.0     0.0
#2015-09-04     0.0     0.0     0.0
#2015-09-05     0.0     1.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom! This gets me half way there, but I also wanted the date index to be "continuous", i.e., I want the array to include the dates: 2015-09-01, 2015-09-02, 2015-09-03, 2015-09-04, 2015-09-05, ... And for the dates that do not have a record to be filled with zeros.

Comment: One option is to reindex your date time index after the `pivot`, see the update.

Comment: That is great -- I appreciate the help!